# how to get key of post in which user is currently signed in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the post id in which user is currently signed in i.e in my case I need this: "-Kqm0-HrwGNgDhvTqOjU" because the current user id is "OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2".

[image: my database structure]

so that I can get the name of currently signed in user

here's my code:

```
public class MyAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mSetupButton;
    private EditText mSetupName;
    private EditText mSetupBio;
    private ImageButton mSetupImageButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private String mPostKey=null;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebasedatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

        DatabaseReference mdatabaseR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebasedatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
        //Toast.makeText(this, "" + currentFirebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        mSetupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountName);
        mSetupBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountBio);
        mSetupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accountButton);
        mSetupImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.accountImageButton);

        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");


        String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference myRef=ref.child(user_id);


        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String obj = objSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this,obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String post_name = (String) objSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                    mSetupName.setText(post_name);

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });



        //Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this,user_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

in "String obj" i'm getting all the post ids because of for loop, but in my case I only need that one in which user is signed in i.e whose uid is "OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2"

Comment: Where is `OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2` and `-Kqm0-HrwGNgDhvTqOjU` in your data structure. I didn't see any.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop every object, like this:

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild('uid').equalTo('your_uid').on("value", 
function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.val());

});
```

Comment: what should i put in place of 'uid' and 'your_uid' @Joaquin Peraza

Comment: This is not java. See the question tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Use a query to find the profile for the user
2. Change your JSON structure to store users under their UID (**recommended**)

### Use a query to find the profile for the user

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo("OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String obj = objSnapshot.getKey();
```

### Change your JSON structure to store users under their UID

If you have a collection of items that have a natural key, you should store those items under their natural key. So in a collection of users, store the users under their UID:

```
profiles
  OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2
    email: "..."
    name: "..."
    phone: "..."
  UIDofuser2
    email: "..."
    name: "..."
    phone: "..."
```

This has many advantages, a few of which are:

- Each UID can by definition only be present once in this structure.
- It's easier to secure access to user profiles (if needed) in this scenario, as [shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable)
- (most important for you) You can access the user without a direct read, instead of needing to query:

  ```
  final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
  DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child("OiHtZxtLUeh63UzudUChEpSODPx2");
  userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          String obj = objSnapshot.getKey();
  ```

  In this last snippet you'll notice that the `Query` is no longer needed, which improves the scalability of your code. While that likely won't make a big difference on a list of users, in other cases it may. Since we do a direct read, we also no longer need the loop in `onDataChange()`, which improves the readability of the code.